# Show all categories and subcategories on a nopcommerce 3.0 website?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I was wondering if anyone knows how to modify the code to make the left hand navigation menu show all the subcategories in addition to categories on the homepage, category, search & product pages?

I just need a push in the right direction.  The code is very complicated but I can tell it's organized very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nopCommerce performs lazy load to get the sub-categories of a category.

To make loading during menu loading will necessary get all sub-categories of all categories.

After obtaining these sub-categories, will need to store these data in the cache to increase performance of the website.

Answer (score 1):

NopCommerce made strange decision for 3.x to load subcategories only of active category and make separate cache for every single category. Reason for this move was to increase performance by preventing loading of thousands of categories from database with single request. This of course doesn't make much sense for say hundreds of categories, it actually makes browsing store with expiring cache slower.

## Load all categories fix

To load all categories including sub-categories you have to change method **PrepareCategoryNavigationModel** in **\Presentation\Nop.Web\Controllers\CatalogController.cs** around line 218

```
for (int i = 0; i <= breadCrumbIds.Count - 1; i++)
if (breadCrumbIds[i] == category.Id)
categoryModel.SubCategories.AddRange(PrepareCategoryNavigationModel(category.Id, breadCrumbIds));
```

to just

```
categoryModel.SubCategories.AddRange(PrepareCategoryNavigationModel(category.Id, breadCrumbIds));
```

## Single navigation cache fix

To make single navigation cache instead of making same cache for every single active category make change around line 1157

```
string cacheKey = string.Format(
    ModelCacheEventConsumer.CATEGORY_NAVIGATION_MODEL_KEY,
    _workContext.WorkingLanguage.Id,
    string.Join(",", customerRolesIds),
    _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id, 
    activeCategoryId);
```

to

```
string cacheKey = string.Format(
    ModelCacheEventConsumer.CATEGORY_NAVIGATION_MODEL_KEY,
    _workContext.WorkingLanguage.Id,
    string.Join(",", customerRolesIds),
    _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id, 
    0);
```

AND

```
var breadCrumb = activeCategory != null ?
    activeCategory.GetCategoryBreadCrumb(categoryService, aclService, storeMappingService).Select(x => x.Id).ToList() : new List<int>();
```

to

```
var breadCrumb = new List<int>();
```

### Note: Update-proof approach

For changes to persist when updating NopCommerce you can duplicate CatalogController.cs/CategoryNavigation as new controller in plugin. Then change views _ColumnsTwo, _ColumnsThree in theme to use this new controller. Or tell NopCommerce to add setting to switch between the two approaches :-P.